# Code explanation requested - Python functions

Tags: python, function

I am hoping someone can explain/answer a few questions about the following code (taken from an online training source, not my code).  I am beginning to learn and practice with functions and this piece of code takes it a step further by linking methods together and referencing a dict:

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}


students=[lloyd,alice,tyler]

for student in students:
    print(student['name'])
    print (student["homework"])
    print (student["quizzes"])
    print (student["tests"])

def average(numbers):
    total=sum(numbers)
    total=float(total)
    media= total/ (len(numbers))
    return media

def get_average(student):
    homework=average(student["homework"])
    quizzes=average(student["quizzes"])
    tests=average(student["tests"])
    final=0.1*homework +0.3*quizzes + 0.6*tests
    return final

def get_letter_grade(score):
    if score >= 90:
        return "A"
    elif score >=80:
        return "B"
    elif score >=70:
        return "C"
    elif score >=60:
        return "D"
    else:
        return "F"

print (get_letter_grade(get_average(lloyd)))
```

My questions are:

1. How does this section below know to reference the dictionary values above it?  I see the list students that happens to have the same values as the dict keys but how does it know to fetch the details from the dictionaries specifically?

   ```
   students=[lloyd,alice,tyler]

   for student in students:
       print(student['name'])
       print (student["homework"])
       print (student["quizzes"])
       print (student["tests"])
   ```
2. If I am reading this correctly the following 2 functions purely gets the average then final average/percentage and can be run as standalone functions for any set of numbers outside of this program, and are NOT tied to the specific students at this point, correct? ?

   ```
   def average(numbers):
       total=sum(numbers)
       total=float(total)
       media= total/ (len(numbers))
       return media

   def get_average(student):
       homework=average(student["homework"])
       quizzes=average(student["quizzes"])
       tests=average(student["tests"])
       final=0.1*homework +0.3*quizzes + 0.6*tests
       return final
   ```

i.e. the 'student' in:

```
    def get_average(student):
```

is not referencing the student in the For loop above it at all, correct?

3. Finally, the section where the functions are "chained" together:

   ```
   print (get_letter_grade(get_average(lloyd)))
   ```

I read this as:  Whatever student you plug in there, it will first fetch the average for that student in the get_average function defined, then from there it works outwards and grabs the letter grade for that number. Switching between students would change the outcome obviously.  Am I reading that correct?  Basically, it works inside out when chaining together in that fashion?

Thanks for any explanation you may have!

** EDIT **  - I'm guessing from all the negative votes on this post that the question was too broad.  I apologize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1. In

```
students=[lloyd,alice,tyler]

for student in students:
    print(student['name'])
    print (student["homework"])
    print (student["quizzes"])
    print (student["tests"])
```

variable `student` will successively hold references to the same objects as do `lloyd`, `alice` and `tyler`. These objects happen to be dictionaries. So e.g. in the first iteration `student` refers to the same dict object as `lloyd`, so `student ['name']` refers to the same dictionary entry as `lloyd ['name']`

A2. Your interpretation is correct

A3. Your interpretation is correct

Comment: ahhh got it, thanks.  I missed the obvious, there are no quotes around lloyd, alice, tyler in the students list [].  So clearly they are referencing other objects.  Thank you for pointing that out.  Now it's clearer to me